# How To Refresh Listview Row From ListviewAdapter-Android

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

Firstly Hello everyone and thanks from now for your helps.

I have a listview with rows which include few textviews and a button. I want to change background image of button when click(for example Facebook "like" button). But when I click on button, it changes the background but i need to refresh list view to see changes.
Are there any way to refresh listview from button which is in raws? By the way notifydatasetchanged() didn't work for me.

Shortly, when you click Like button below a post on Facebook,it turns blue. I m trying to do same thing.

This code belongs to adapter class;

```
fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(getItem(position).isFav)
                fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.nonfavorite);
            else {
                addToFavorites(getItem(position));    

            }
        }
    });
```

And this one is belongs to row xml;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/textlayout_shape">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lwraw_clickableLayout">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lwrowHeader_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lwrowSender_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lwrowBody_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/lwrowHeader_textview"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lwrowType_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/lwraw_clickableLayout"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lwrowDate_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/lwrow_clickableLayout"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lwrowFavorite_btn"
    android:src="@drawable/nonfavorite"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/lwrowDate_textview"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/lwrowDate_textview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Please paste the xml and java code you're working with.

Comment: notifydatasetchanged only changes the data of the adapter, please do show your code as a [mcve]

Comment: Do you mean that when you click a button, you want to know which button is clicked and reveal the change in your data source?